# VB.net: Object not set to an instance of object

Tags: vb.net

I am getting a Object not set to an instance of object error. I have put  a list view where all messages should be shown. I am using [lumisoft sample code](http://www.lumisoft.ee/lswww/download/downloads/Examples/pop3_client_app.zip)  which I ported to vb.net

```
 Private Sub FillMessagesList()
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
        Try
            Dim m_pPop3 As POP3_Client = Nothing
            For Each message As POP3_ClientMessage In m_pPop3.Messages
                Dim mime As Mail_Message = Mail_Message.ParseFromByte(message.HeaderToByte())

                Dim item As New ListViewItem()
                If mime.From IsNot Nothing Then
                    item.Text = mime.From.ToString()
                Else
                    item.Text = "<none>"
                End If

                If String.IsNullOrEmpty(mime.Subject) Then
                    item.SubItems.Add("<none>")
                Else
                    item.SubItems.Add(mime.Subject)
                End If

                item.SubItems.Add(mime.[Date].ToString())
                item.SubItems.Add(CDec(message.Size / CDec(1000)).ToString("f2") & " kb")
                item.Tag = message
                ListView1.Items.Add(item)
            Next
        Catch x As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(Me, "Errorssssss: " + x.Message)
        End Try
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.[Default]
    End Sub
```

Comment: Step through it and see which line is throwing the exception. You'll likely be able to figure it out from there.

Comment: Well I tried , I think  Dim item As New ListViewItem()............End if is giving error

Comment: That line will not create a NullReferenceException. This exception type is typically a "dot" exception, where the thing that you're putting the dot on is null. The answers below appear to be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
Dim m_pPop3 As POP3_Client = Nothing
For Each message As POP3_ClientMessage In m_pPop3.Messages
```

You set `m_pPop3` to Nothing and then try to access one of its members.

You say that you ported the code - perhaps you need to look back at the original code and port it correctly:

```
private POP3_Client m_pPop3 = null;

/// <summary>
/// Default constructor.
/// </summary>
public wfrm_Main()
{
    InitUI();

    this.Visible = true;

    wfrm_Connect frm = new wfrm_Connect(
        new EventHandler<WriteLogEventArgs>(Pop3_WriteLog));
    if(frm.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK){
        m_pPop3 = frm.POP3; 
    // etc...
}

private void FillMessagesList()
{
    this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
    try{
        foreach(POP3_ClientMessage message in m_pPop3.Messages){
        // etc...
    }
}
```

Notice that `m_pPop3.Messages` is a private member here, not a local variable as you have implemented it.

To correct your code I would suggest changing it to be more similar to the original. Change the local variable to a private member and set it in the constructor, just as the original C# code does.

Comment: I am not good at porting C# to vb.net ,, i tried asking for help in an another post but it got closed. Can you help me out where else I have  to correct my self to avoid that error

Comment: but vb says "Private m_pPop3 As POP3_Client = Nothing" is wrong.... it has to be "Dim m_pPop3 As POP3_Client = Nothing"

Comment: "m_pPop3 = frm.POP3"...............Says 'POP3' is not a member of 'WindowsApplication1.Form1".............6 other errors saying "Name 'm_pPop3' is not declared."

Answer (score 0):

The culprit is possibly from the code in the 2 lines:

```
 Dim m_pPop3 As POP3_Client = Nothing
            For Each message As POP3_ClientMessage In m_pPop3.Messages
```

You're trying to loop through the messages in "m_pPop3" but you've explicitly set it to nothing on the line directly above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it's here since you're setting m_pPop3 to Nothing. If you'd stepped through the code it would show you that.

```
Dim m_pPop3 As POP3_Client = Nothing
For Each message As POP3_ClientMessage In m_pPop3.Messages
```

Comment: but when I put Dim m_pPop3 As POP3_Client = Nothing
 anywhere else like Form load it shows m_pPop3 as not declared